# Creating basic captcha in javascript

Tags: javascript, captcha

So, I wanted to create captcha that generates 5 random numbers inside the text input on every page reload. When I run the function, it wont work, so I'm wondering why.
 
Here is the HTML:

```
    <input type="text" id="ver" onload="captchaCreate()" disabled></input>
```

Here is the function in javascript:

```
function captchaCreate(){
    var niz = new Array(5);
    for (var i; i<=5; i++){
        niz[i] = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    }
        document.getElementById("ver").value = niz.join("");
}
```

Comment: Well... I doubt that this will be useful in any way, what do you want to do with a client-side-captcha?

Comment: And your function is needlessly complicated. You can get the same result with `(1e6 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1e6) + '').slice(-6)`.

Comment: Input elements don't have an `onload` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, creating a clientside captcha is pretty useless

As for your code, inputs don't have an onload event and you need to assign the var you want to loop because `undefined + 1` is `NaN`

```js
window.onload = function() {
  captchaCreate();
}

function captchaCreate(){
    var niz = new Array(5);
    for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
        niz[i] = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    }
    document.getElementById("ver").value = niz.join("");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="ver" disabled></input>
```

Comment: It should also be `<` rather than `<=`.

Comment: It's an assignment from javascript. Thanks for your help mate, appreciate it. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

to load the fonction when you refresh the page you can use

```
window.onload = function() {
  captchaCreate();
}
```

or just :

```
captchaCreate();
```

you can do this with JS or PHP, but PHP launches once when loading the page
(you said that you need to call the function only when you refresh the page. So if you want you can use php ^^ )

this works good for me :

```
function captchaCreate(){
    var ar = new Array(5);
    for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
        ar[i] = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    }
    document.getElementById("your_div").value = ar.join("");
}
```